# SharePoint 2013 user profile policy: auto follow people from team -- what's a team?

Tags: following

Under Manage Profile Service page, in the People section, click Manage Policies. There is a policy "Auto Follow People from team".

May I know what is the definition of "Team" in this policy? In our farm, the users in the same "Division" (which around 100 users) are following each other. This "Division" is a custom properites we added. So I think this policy is not rely on user profile property to define a "team".

So what would be the "team" criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have seen in SharePoint 2013 On premise is that you automatically follow people that have the same `Manager` as you in their User Profiles, so if you use AD sync it would be the `reportsTo` field from the AD that is used by default.